# Iterate from a Doctrine_Query

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, loops

I am using Doctrine 1.2 in a symfony project.

I would like to iterate with doctrine, I have a Doctrine_Query object, I want to iterate on the "result set" of this query because I can have 100K records and don't want to run out of memory.

Something like :

```
$it = $query->iterate();
while($it->next()) {
  $obj = $it->getOjbect();
  //Do some stuff with this object
}
```

I figured out how todo by using a custom hydrator.

For a symfony project, in ProjectConfiguration.class.php :

```
public function configureDoctrine(Doctrine_Manager $manager)
{
  $manager->registerHydrator('my_hydrator', 'Doctrine_Hydrator_MyHydrator');
}
```

In a controller :

```
$this->filename = $query->execute(array(), 'my_hydrator');

Added in lib folder : 

class Doctrine_Hydrator_MyHydrator extends Doctrine_Hydrator_Abstract
{
    public function hydrateResultSet($stmt)
    {
      $filename = sfConfig::get('sf_data_dir').'/'.time().'.csv';
      $fh = fopen($filename,'w');
      while($f = $stmt->fetch(Doctrine_Core::FETCH_BOTH)){
        $f = array(
            $f[0],
            $f[1],
            $f[2],
            $f[3],
            $f[4],
            $f[5],
            $f[6],
            $f[7],
            $f[8],
        );
        fputcsv($fh, $f); 
      }
      fclose($fh); 
      return $filename;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned about running out of memory, you should look into returning the results as arrays instead of objects.

This will of course mean you can't then use the results as objects (so you can't do $row->save()), which for 100k records, you probably shouldn't need anyway

From the [documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/working-with-models/en#fetching-objects):

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
->select('u.id, u.username, p.phonenumber')
->from('User u')
->leftJoin('u.Phonenumbers p');

$results = $q->execute(array(), Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

Comment: I will have to create a csv file where each row contains from 1 to 10 properties of each object. $results can contains up to 100K array so I will run out of memory. I cannot use execute().

Comment: Do you *need* to return 100k? Have you looked at paginating the results?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes the pagination (sfDoctrinePager) may be a solution. But before that I want to make sure if it is possible or not to do something like: $stmt = $this->maindb->prepareStatement($sql);
        $stmt->setInt(1, $nid);
        $rs= $stmt->executeQuery();

        
        while($rs->next()) {
            ...
        }